# Can not add code comment inside GatsbyJS function

Tags: javascript, html, gatsby

[image]

How I add code comment inside this Gatsby function. I search in web but not found yet.

Comment: `<!-- This is an HTML comment -->`

Comment: Not working  Does this is VS Code editor problem? Idk.

Comment: You should be more specific about "not working". Where are you adding the comment? What errors do you get?

Comment: <!-- This is an HTML comment --> This way is not working. {/* Code comment here */} This way is working.

Comment: @OneCricketeer this looks like JSX, not HTML, which doesn't support normal HTML comments. You have to use `{/*comment*/}` syntax instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
   export default () => {
     // your comment here
      return <div>
               <NavBar />
               {/* another comment here*/}
               Hello People
               <hr />
               <Link to="/blog/">Blog Page</Link>
             <div>     
                
    }
```

Note that I've self-closed the empty tags.

---

Adding the comment of [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642943/oliver):

> To be precise, the syntax of HTML inside JS is called JSX, and it's a
> syntactic extension to JavaScript typically employed by React (and
> thus GatsbyJS) for cleaner code. To embed a JS expression in JSX you
> need to use curly braces like this: `{some expression}`. Note that the
> expression can be a comment, hence the `{/*comment*/}`

Comment: Your answer is right but i want to add comment inside those div

Comment: Updated. Use `{/* comment */}`

Comment: To be precise, the syntax of HTML inside JS is called JSX, and it's a syntactic extension to JavaScript typically employed by React (and thus GatsbyJS) for cleaner code. To embed a JS expression in JSX you need to use curly braces like this: `{some expression}`. Note that the expression can be a comment, hence the `{/*comment*/}` syntax. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

So The question was "How to add comment inside Gatsby JS function" That was a Tricky question. Actually I want to comment inside div elements. I found the solution. So t want to answer on my own.

Comment inside function but outside div element's @ferran-buireu is right but inside div element code comment be like;

```
{/* code comment */}
```

Comment: To be precise, the syntax of HTML inside JS is called JSX, and it's a syntactic extension to JavaScript typically employed by React (and thus GatsbyJS) for cleaner code. To embed a JS expression in JSX you need to use curly braces like this: `{some expression}`. Note that the expression can be a comment, hence the `{/*comment*/}` syntax inside the JSX code. Outside of JSX you can use `//comment` like normal. Hope this helps!